# How to save customized config export in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to use "CSV for Excel" in export  as default method in phpmyadmin.

I read that doc, but cannot find the infot I am looking for.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 3):

Edit `config.inc.php` and add the line

```
$cfg['Export']['format'] = 'csv';
```

You can see a lot more export options in `libraries/config.default.php` if you wish to further customize your export defaults.

Answer (score -1):

Open your phpmyadmin. be sure phpmyadmin version > 3.0
Click "Export" tab
Select "Custom - display all possible options" button in "Export Method:"
Select Required tables.
Select "CSV for MS-excel" in "Format" Select field, to receive "CSV" file

Comment: well I KNOW that: but how to Make this CSV for MS-EXCEL as DEFAULT choice ?